# Why isn't my file opening? I have had this problem with other programs within visual studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, file

I am new to C++ and I am trying to open and read from a file into a simple program that I have Made. Here it is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream myFile("Otto.txt");
    myFile.open("Otto.txt");

    if (!myFile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Sorry, an error has occured";
    }

    string read;
    while (myFile >> read)
    {
        cout << read;
    }
    
    myFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Here's my Otto.txt file:

```
Hello
I 
Am
Otto!
```

I am using Visual Studio 2019. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Make sure your file is in the current working directory. In Visual Studio that is not necessarily the same location as the .exe file.

Comment: You file needs to be in the same folder that your source files are in.

Comment: By only giving the filename and not the *full path*, you are relying on the file being in the current working directory.  To convince yourself the file can be opened, give the full path name, i.e. `ifstream myFile("c:\\somedirectory\\Otto.txt");`.  If that can't be opened, then the file either doesn't exist, or you don't have permissions set to open it, or some other external issue.

Answer (score 1):

Attempting to open a file on an `ifstream` object that is already associated with an open file will cause the (second) open operation to fail, which will cause the stream to enter a failed state.

In your code, you are opening the file twice, once in the constructor of `myFile` and once in the `open` function call.

The solution is to only open the file once, either in the constructor, or in an `open` function call, but not both.

Comment: I understand, but even after taking out the open function call the file will still not be read. I somewhat think this is an issue regarding visual studio or perhaps something externally. If you think there any issues that have caused this ill be glad to hear it.

Comment: Does the file `Otto.txt` exist at all in your current working directory? You can print the current working directory using [`_getcwd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getcwd-wgetcwd?view=msvc-160) or [`GetCurrentDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcurrentdirectory).

Comment: @Vertek: If you are using C++17 or higher (which should be supported by Visual Studio 2019), you can also obtain the current working directory using [`std::filesystem::current_path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path).